# On Duplicate Key Update syntax php/mysql Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do a query which updates if 'ID' exists and inserts if it doesn't exists. When the tried to run the following query, i could see so many duplicate records being inserted. I dont know what i am doing wrong. My query is below. Id is the 'Autoincrement' and 'KEY'. I am not getting any query Errors. DB is Mysql

```
    while ($i < $size) {
        $sl= $_POST['sl'][$i];
        $item_id= $_POST['item_id'][$i];
        $item_name= $_POST['item_name'][$i];
        $prod_description=$_POST['prod_description'][$i];
        $prod_description= mysql_real_escape_string($prod_description);
        $item_quantity= $_POST['item_quantity'][$i];
        $item_units= $_POST['item_units'][$i];
        $unitprice= $_POST['unitprice'][$i];
        $total=$_POST['total'][$i];
        $currency_selected=$_POST['currency_change'][$i];
        $total_inr= $_POST['total_inr'][$i];
            $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
        $item_quantity_sup= $_POST['item_quantity_sup'][$i];
        $slab_range= $_POST['slab_range'][$i];
        $item_units_sup= $_POST['item_units_sup'][$i];
        $item_partno= $_POST['item_partno'][$i];
        $ifmain= $_POST['ifmain'][$i];
        $sup_itempartno = $_POST['sup_itempartno'][$i];

$query = "INSERT INTO comparitive_st_sup (
id, 
tender_id, 
item_id, 
ifmain, 
slno, 
item_name, 
item_partno, 
prod_description, 
sup_itempartno, 
currency, 
slab_range, 
qty, 
total_inr, 
qty_sup, 
item_units, 
item_units_sup, 
unitprice, 
total, 
supplier_name
) 
VALUES (
$id, 
'$tender_id', 
'$item_id',
'$ifmain', 
'$sl', 
'$item_name', 
'$item_partno',
'$prod_description', 
'$sup_itempartno', 
'$currency_selected', 
'$slab_range', 
'$item_quantity', 
'$total_inr', 
'$item_quantity_sup', 
'$item_units', 
'$item_units_sup', 
'$unitprice', 
'$total', 
'$supplier_name2'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
ifmain='$ifmain', 
slno = '$sl',
item_name = '$item_name',
item_partno = '$item_partno',
prod_description = '$prod_description',
sup_itempartno = '$sup_itempartno',
currency = '$currency_selected',
slab_range= '$slab_range',
qty = '$item_quantity',
qty_sup = '$item_quantity_sup',
item_units = '$item_units',
item_units_sup = '$item_units_sup',
unitprice = '$unitprice',
total = '$total', 
total_inr='$total_inr'";

        mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    ++$i;
    }
```

The actual scenario is . I have some records in my db. I call the records in edit mode. In this mode the users can add some rows (Dynamic rows) and they can update. So which ever records exists should be updated and the newly added rows should be inserted to the table.

Answer (score 1):

An `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query will Insert before it updates so if your unique key is auto-incrementing, it will first insert a new record then look to update but because it is never the same, it will never update.

Comment: The actual scenario is . I have some records in my db. I call the records in edit mode. In this mode the users can add some rows (Dynamic rows) and they can update. So which ever records exists should be updated and the newly added rows should be inserted to the table.

Comment: Have you tried to change your query to include what I suggested?

Comment: Wait a second, if your ID is autoincrement, it will never update because it is always going to be different for each record

Comment: Or may be the insert statement is in a WHILE loop that's why its duplicating? I have updated the question with the actual while loop which iam using.

Comment: But the way an Insert and Update query works is it inserts first then looks to update. So in your case, it autoincrements and then will try to update but because the id is different, it will not update

Comment: ohh ok... iam understanding.. so i guess in this case ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will not work?

Comment: No it will not. I suggest making another column UNIQUE so that it checks against that instead of against the ID. Alternatively you can remove the autoincrement setting

Comment: Yeah sure i will do that. meanwhile i will wait for somemore time if anyone gives me another solution to achieve this. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `INTO` keyword:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comparitive_st_sup (id, tender_id) 
                             VALUES ( $id, '$tender_id')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tender_id='$tender_id'";
```

Comment: The actual scenario is . I have some records in my db. I call the records in edit mode. In this mode the users can add some rows (Dynamic rows) and they can update. So which ever records exists should be updated and the newly added rows should be inserted to the table.

Comment: Did you check your data before the insert ? Are you sure the id is passed correctly ?

Comment: Could you try the query i put in my answer and see if it create new row. Also test your query in mysql console and see if it works.

Comment: No its not inserting any record.

Comment: So the mysql command works fine ? If yes you have a problem in your php code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `INSERT INGORE`?
It will insert a row if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, it will skip.

Comment: The actual scenario is . I have some records in my db. I call the records in edit mode. In this mode the users can add some rows (Dynamic rows) and they can update. So which ever records exists should be updated and the newly added rows should be inserted to the table.